# Problema de lógica en recorrido PHP

Tags: php, css

Tengo un botón para **RESERVAR** que me lleva a una página de **confirmación_reserva.php** en esa página tengo los detalles de la compra, y dos opciones: **Cancelar** o **Reservar**. Ambos botones redirigen a pago.php, pero dentro de pago hay restricciones.

Si pulso Cancelar me devuelve a **cancelando.php** durante 2 segundos y luego se redirige a **index.php**, en cambio, si pulso Reservar me lleva a **pago.php**

Mi **problema** está en **Cancelar**, debido a que me muestra la página de "**cancelando.php**" durante 2 segundos pero esa página tiene una estructura incorrecta (ver imagen).

**¿Por qué no me muestra correctamente la página de cancelando.php?**

**Código:**

```
<?php
    include_once "Clases/BD.php";

    //Iniciar una nueva sesión o reanudar la existente.
    session_start();

    //Si existe la sesión "cliente"..., la guardamos en una variable.
    if (isset($_SESSION['cliente'])){
        $cliente = $_SESSION['cliente'];
    }else{
        //Si no existe la sesión y queremos actualizar la página para realizar de nuevo el pago, no lo permite
        //y redirige a iniciar_sesion_cliente.php
        header("Location: iniciar_sesion_cliente.php");
    }

    //Si existe y ha sido pulsado el botón "Cancelar"...
    if(isset($_POST["cancelar"])){
        include "cancelando.php";
        header("Refresh:2; url=index.php");
    }else{
        $idcabana = $_SESSION["idcabana"];
        $idemail = $cliente;
        $check_in = $_SESSION["check_in"];
        $check_out = $_SESSION["check_out"];
        $personas = $_SESSION["personas"];
        $pago_total = $_SESSION["pago_total"];

        //Si existe y hemos pulsado el botón "Reservar"...
        if(isset($_POST["reservar"])){
            //Llamamos al método "realizarReserva" y le pasamos los parámetros del formulario.
            $resultado = BD::confirmarPago($idcabana, $pago_total, "TARJETA"); //El modo de pago por defecto es TARJETA.
            if($resultado){
                session_destroy();
            }
        }
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Realizado pago</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos_pago.css">
    </head>

    <body background="imagenes/fondo_campo3.jpg">
        <?php
        //Si no existe la variable de sesión...     
        if(!isset($_SESSION["cliente"])){
            //Refrescamos la página a los 0 segundos.
            header("Refresh:0; url=iniciar_sesion_cliente.php");
        //Si existe la variable de sesión...
        }else{
            $idcabana = $_SESSION["idcabana"];
            $idemail = $cliente;
            $check_in = $_SESSION["check_in"];
            $check_out = $_SESSION["check_out"];
            $personas = $_SESSION["personas"];
            $pago_total = $_SESSION["pago_total"];

            //Si existe y hemos pulsado el botón "Reservar"...
            echo "<div id='detalles_reserva'>";
            echo 
                "<p id='pagado'>PAGADO</p>".
                "<img src='imagenes/cabaña.png' height='22px' width='22px' alt='cabaña'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Cabaña: ".$idcabana."
                <br/><br/>".
                "<img src='imagenes/email.png' height='22px' width='22px' alt='cabaña'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Email: ".$idemail."
                <br/><br/>".
                "<img src='imagenes/calendario.jpg' height='22px' width='22px' alt='check_in'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Check_in: ".$check_in."
                <br/><br/>".
                "<img src='imagenes/calendario.jpg' height='22px' width='22px' alt=check_out'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Check_out: ".$check_out."
                <br/><br/>".
                "<img src='imagenes/personas.jpg' height='22px' width='22px' alt='personas'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Personas: ".$personas."
                <br/><br/>".
                "<img src='imagenes/euros.jpg' height='22px' width='22px' alt='pago_total'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Pago total: ".$pago_total."€
                <br/><br/><br/>
                <center><a class='enlace_azul' href='index.php'>Volver al inicio</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href='javascript:window.print()'>Imprimir</a></center>
                ";
            echo "</div>";
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Código:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Cancelando pago</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/cancelando.css">
    </head>

    <body background="imagenes/fondo_campo4.jpg">
        <div id="imagen_cancelando">
            <img src="imagenes/cancelado.png" alt="cancelando" height="200px" width="380px"/>
        </div>

        <div id="imagen_cargando">
            <center><img src="imagenes/cargando.gif" alt="cargando" height="40px" width="40px"/></center>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

El div de pagado debería NO ser mostrado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El div te sigue apareciendo porque solo estas realizando una inclusión, mas no estas borrando el contenido que estaba anteriormente.

Comment: ¿Cómo se arreglaría?

Comment: Si te entiendo bien tienes 3 archivos, **iniciar_sesion_cliente.php**, **cancelando.php**  y  **index.php**, es correcto?

Comment: Así es, esos 3 archivos entre tantos. Creo haberlo arreglado poniendo después del include la función die(); para romper lo siguiente que leyese el programa.

Comment: Es correcto, esa es una de varias soluciones pero a mi parecer es la mas idonea

Answer (score 1):

Solo agrega la función `exit()` o `die()` despues del `include "cancelando.php";` y asi evitas el cargue del contenido posterior, el `header("Refresh:2; url=index.php");` no seria necesario a menos que lo utilices para limpiar el contenido nuevamente.